# fs.readFile, if file content is a path to another file, behaved differently on Mac and Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js

I ran into a problem that if file content is a string which is actually a path to another file, fs.readFile will get the content of that file, for example,

file A content

```
/path/to/fileB
```

and call

```
fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
```

on Mac, the result of fs.readFile was the content of fileB, but on Windows, it was the string '/path/to/fileB'

Which behavior is right? How to keep the result same on both Mac and Windows?

In fact, I personally love the Mac behavior.

Comment: try to read it with specified encoding: fs.readFile(path, {'encoding': 'utf8'}, callback)

Comment: I forgot to mention the encoding was used already, updated post.

Comment: @fifth how was the file created? it sounds like a `soft link`, which only work on unix-like systems (MacOS, linux)

Comment: @Munim, it's a symbolic file, I just realized the root cause. How to get it worked on Windows? cygwin?

Comment: @fifth but what behaviour do you expect in Windows? You can try to first use fs.lstat(filepath, function(st)) and check if it's symbolic link (st.isSymbolicLink()), if yes then just read it, if not then read the content and use the content as the path to destination file.

Comment: @fifth it may work on node.js on cygwin, I don't know. Honestly, I wouldn't bother with it, as I usually write server apps and my target deployment platform is always linux based.

Comment: I just tried both possible solution. First, st.isSymboliLink() can't correctly tell if it's a symbolic link on Windows. Secondly, node unfortunately doesn't work on cygwin.

Comment: @fifth what do you mean "can't correctly tell if it's a symbolic link on Windows" I would suppose that it should always return false on Windows, as far as I know there is no such think as links on windows (and shortcuts are not links right?).

Comment: @tomekK, I meant it returned false always. Yes, it was a linux symbolic link which shouldn't be correctly handled on Windows. But it was a text file, now I read the content of this file, resolve the path, then read the content from real path. It's just a limited workaround, not a generic solution, but it worked anyway.